# Azure messages pattern

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, microsoft-message-analyzer

Right now, on IoT Hub there is an information that limit for messages per day 8000. I would like to ask you about any patterns which are being used in Azure.

I am curious if I am able to hit to Azure with some service outside Messages in order to prevent it from being overloaded by big amount of data, or save some confidentiality for this service.

For example, I would like to store some data from given service to Messages that are not being confidential and other data by using some WebSocket or any Rest protocol. I think that there are some patterns that serve that scenarios.

Does anyone has experience with that kind of situation?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more 'For example, I would like to store some data from given service to Messages that are not being confidential and other data by using some WebSocket or any Rest protocol. I think that there are some patterns that serve that scenarios.' ? 
What do you mean by 'to Messages that are not being confidential'? What does it mean 'other data' in this context?

Comment: have a look at the IoT Hub limits https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#iot-hub-limits As you can see, the limit for messages per day 8000 is for development (exploring) case **F1 Free** and the production tiers such as S1, S2 and S3 allow from 400K - 300M messages/unit/day.

Comment: @kgalic my point is that if I'm using IoT Hub to transfer data from device to cloud then I would like to have some assurance that not all data goes through Messages service, but only most important ones. In context you mentioned I mean that I'd rather prefer not to transfer all data from devices (Let's say there are 10 video cameras which are being streamed to IoT Hub) to Messages but only some part of them (only critical data and in accordance with standards) and other ones transfer through other services like REST API.

Comment: @wmk There is upcoming a new feature (currently still in the preview) in the Azure IoT Hub such as a **device streams**, see more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-streams-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything needs to go through IoT Hub.  IoT Hub is great for two way communication to/from IoT devices.  You could also look at Event Hubs for ingestion from devices that don't need two way comms.  We have a write up on the differences here [Connecting IoT Devices to Azure: IoT Hub and Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-compare-event-hubs).

[image]